# ng-click not firing click method in IOS build using Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building a Hybrid App using Ionic framework and Cordova.
I've installed couple of plugins and everything is working fine in Android.
When I built app for IOS using XCode and trying to test in Simulator or iPad device, I'm getting issues with touch events.

Everywhere where I supposed to touch once(ng-click), it is not firing click method. If I tap 2 times in short span immediately(probably standard 300ms delay), then able to get it fired.

Can anybody please guide on the touch/tap issue.

Comment: Are you using any other library for handling touch, like Hammer.js etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The tap issue got resolved, I've included mobile-angular-ui library in Ionic framework app, and it is causing the touch issues. I removed mobile-ui library and the issue got resolved.